# button name last letters

Tags: c#, button, lastindexof

I have about about 30 buttons each contain text and then a number and i just need to put the number in the other button

like in the example button1.Name should be test3

Is this possible?

i know that LastIndexOf doesnt work like this, it's for giving the idea what i want to adchieve

```
button1 = "hello1"; //this varies in normal program
button2 = "notimportant3"; //this varies in normal program

button1.Name = "test"+button2.Name.LastIndexOf(1);
```

Comment: I don't think LastIndexOf is used properly here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button1.Name = "test" + button2.Name[button2.Name.Length-1];
```

or better use string.Format() to format the string

like

```
button1.Name  = string.Format("test{0}", button2.Name[button2.Name.Length-1]);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why post more or less the same answer? :P

Comment: Because sometimes people can post at the same time.

Comment: i totally love this site :D Thanks! ill Accept it over a while

Answer (score 1):

```
button1.Name  = string.Format("test{0}", button2.Name[button2.Name.Length - 1]);
```

Comment: @Kapein Not a problem - you could extend this, if you want to check that the last character is a number for example if that's what it has to be :)